# iOS Layout - Whats the best solution?

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode-storyboard

For an iOS app i am currently working on, I need to manage the controls displayed on the screen based on the type of device the app is running on.

I will try to explain with a theoretical example (the actual numbers used below are not important, what interests me is best method to achieve the desired result).

Example:

[image]
[image]

In the case of the app in the screenshots, the button that overlaps the UIImageView should not be displayed at all OR displayed in another place on the screen.

So far I've worked with autolayout , but , from what i could figure, there's no way to say to xcode something like: hey, for a class size "Compact Width / Compact Height" , I want you to hide these buttons...but show them for "Regular Width / Compact Height" .

I also did some googling and saw some people talk about using different storyboards based on the device; I am also thinking, I could add/remove buttons dynamically based on the device type , but I think it's not so pleasant to have to add all of the constraints by hand (programatically that is).

So to resume, I would appreciate a suggestion of a 'best' way to do this , best meaning a combination of 'not so hard' + ' not so long'. Also, some code example (or links) would be highly appreciated.

Thank you all in advance !

Comment: Why not just make the buttons shrink if they are going to overlap the image view?

Comment: Its an idea, but i dont think it works well if i have more that 1 button overlapping. Maybe I am not using the best practices by wanting the buttons to have fixed sizes.

Comment: You can say to Xcode `hey, for a class size "Compact Width / Compact Height" , I want you to hide these buttons...but show them for "Regular Width / Compact Height"`. In a Size Class you can choose if interface objects appear or not using the `installed` tick box in the Attributes Inspector. Is this what you are looking for? Have I misunderstood your requirement?

Comment: You're right, I totally did not notice the little "+" sign near the Installed checkbox. But while testing your answer, I realised that actually the 'smallest' size class, includes 3 screen sizes , and this would still not completely solve my issue(s). But don't get me wrong, your answer is very helpful (for me at least) - in the end I might stick with a combination of this and something else if I dont want to handle the autolayout programmatically.

Comment: If you want my advice (and you may not), I would try to stick to Size Classes and autolayout. Then use code to adjust objects and constraints if more customisation is required. Once you get into one Storyboards per device and trying to distinguish between device screen *physical* sizes you are fighting the frameworks and opening a whole world of pain to maintain that code.

Comment: I am going to take your advice, and try to make the most of size classes and autolayout; and maybe combine it with some of the suggestions @NilsZiehn gave me. Will post back here when I have a final solution.

Comment: How about "hiding" buttons by setting constraints that move the items well off the screen? Note, if you show them in landscape but "hide" them in portrait (or vice versa), the user will see the buttons go flying off the screen when the device rotates and will probably report that as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think it all depends how sophisticated it gets what you are doing overall. When you look at developer's code for large app projects very little is actually done in interface builder since the apps are so dynamic it's just too much work in IB.

Using multiple storyboards 'sounds' like a good idea, but often isn't. If you want to update/change one, in most cases you then have to change the other ones as well.

What I think is handy:

Use one storyboard (or multiple but for different parts of you app and not parallel ones) and then put in very 'special' cases multiple ViewControllers of the same class for the different size into the single storyboard. That way you won't forget about updating the second (and third) because they are all right there.

I would only use multiple 'parallel' storyboards for apps that support iPhone and iPad and it makes sense to really split them up..

Also:

I would as fas as possible still use just one representation and derive the other 'versions' from that in code. If you build a structured user interface you can then reuse (or just inherit) the code that 'hides' parts of the first viewController in the next. That way your code AND your IB files won't get cluttered.

Also think about internationalisation (if that is part of your future plans), since multiple IB documents and multiple instances of the same viewController layout really don't help for that ;)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this part: "Use one storyboard (or multiple but for different parts of you app and not parallel ones) and then put in very 'special' cases multiple ViewControllers of the same class for the different size into the single storyboard. That way you won't forget about updating the second (and third) because they are all right there." - maybe its because I'm tired, but I do not really understand the process you're suggesting.

Comment: I tried to say this: I would only split storyboards if the first one has just too many ViewControllers. To solve your problem, if you want to have two different layout descriptions for the same screen but different sized iOS devices, I would in general put them into the same storyboard just with different identifiers. This way you if you change something that would effect both, they are both right there. BUT:I would only go this path if this doesn't happen for every single view but just for a few with drastic differences.

Comment: When you talk about "different identifiers" you reffer to views (like the main containers) or buttons (or other UI elements) ? Basically, I need this for just  the 'main' view since all the other views can be handled using autolayout and size classes.

Comment: I am talking about the 'identifier' field of the viewController in the storyboard